# symfony : how to check bundles memory usage

Tags: php, symfony, memory, memory-management

In my symfony application, when I dump php memory usage at the beginning of my actions or right after the `$response = $kernel->handle($request);` of the app_dev.php, I get its using about 60Mb of memory. The same when using app.php.

I understand it's a lot too much so I'm trying to understand how I could correct my application.

Is there a way I could dump the memory usage for each bundle? I've not found a simple way.

My bundle list:

```
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle(),
            new FOS\ElasticaBundle\FOSElasticaBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new Genemu\Bundle\FormBundle\GenemuFormBundle(),
            new Gregwar\CaptchaBundle\GregwarCaptchaBundle(),
            new Ivory\OrderedFormBundle\IvoryOrderedFormBundle(),
            new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle($this),
            new JMS\TranslationBundle\JMSTranslationBundle(),
            new JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\JMSI18nRoutingBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
            new Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle(),
            new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
            new Vipx\BotDetectBundle\VipxBotDetectBundle(),
            new WhiteOctober\PagerfantaBundle\WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\GaufretteBundle\KnpGaufretteBundle(),
            new Dizda\CloudBackupBundle\DizdaCloudBackupBundle(),
            new Liuggio\ExcelBundle\LiuggioExcelBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),

//            new Sonata\IntlBundle\SonataIntlBundle(),
//            new HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle(),
//            new Intaro\TwigSandboxBundle\IntaroTwigSandboxBundle(),
//            new WhiteOctober\TCPDFBundle\WhiteOctoberTCPDFBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new JMS\DebuggingBundle\JMSDebuggingBundle($this);
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
            $bundles[] = new RaulFraile\Bundle\LadybugBundle\RaulFraileLadybugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }
```

Comment: *I understand it's a lot too much* Can you please explain why you wrote this? What is the expected value? Is there a *common* value measured by other users? And you have to remember that the `dev` environment load more classes than the `prod` environment.

Comment: Look at : https://blackfire.io/

Comment: thanks; i've installed blackfire but it's a bit overwhelming... memory usage is given for every function call, not by bundle. I'll try to make somehting with it though. As for a common value, I've had someone tell he would begin controller actions with 5Mb of memory usage for regular projects

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Symfony's debug bar enabled? you can check each requests time and find where the usage is happening, or else, try blackfire.io as @Perroin suggested